# K-means++ requires OpenCV although it is installed

Tags: opencv, deep-learning, k-means, darknet

I am trying to run darknet anchoring, but I keep getting an error:

```
k-means++ can't be used without OpenCV, because there is used cvKMeans2 implementation
```

I don't understand this as I get:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.4.3'
```

But I get a different OpenCV version, when I am trying to run Yolo_Mark:

```
~/Yolo_mark$ cmake .
-- Found OpenCV: /usr/local (found version "4.0.0")
```

How can I link these things to work correctly?

Comment: Have you installed multiple versions of OpenCV?